# Android XML Naming convention

Tags: android, xml

Even though the standard name conversion for XML seems to be like "`myName`" and not "`my_name`" or "`my-name`", XML files in Android use "`my_name`" name conversion (`android:title="@string/action_settings"`)

Therefore, I wonder, do I have just to be down with that, is that a standard name conversion Android uses?

Comment: I believe there is no convention for this yet, be creative and find your self one, that makes you and your team life easier.

Comment: Android uses `_` instead-of camelcase style.

Comment: Completely agree with Pankaj.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `camelCase` but `underscore_style` makes things more consistent.

Many resource identifiers in `R` are derived from file names in `res` and the file names can only contain `[a-z0-9._]` so e.g. upper case is not allowed. `R.id` identifiers are special as they are not derived from file names. Still it makes sense to make them follow the same naming rules as the file-based resource identifiers.